# Solving a system of differential equations, which depend on parameters, and visualizing the solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, manipulate

Shortly put, I would like to solve a system consisting of two differential equations, which depend on 3 parameters $\lambda,\sigma 0, \sigma a$ (these are some constant numbers), then I would like to visualize the solution. Of course, if we choose a specific triple of constants, it is easy to solve the equations. I  would like to see how the solution behaves, upon changing parameters. Below is what I tried so far

```
λ = -1.2
r0 = 0.3089
Ω0 = Sqrt[r0] + 1
σ0 = -0.2
σa = -0.5
σ[z] = σ0 + σa*z/(1 + z)
deq2 = -2*(1 + z)*h[z]*D[h[z], z] + 3*h[z]^2 - 
4*h[z]*Ω[z] + Ω[z]^2 + 
2*(1 + z)*h[z]*Ω[z]
deq3 = -1/3*(4*h[z]*Ω[z] - Ω[z]^2 - 2*(1 + z)*h[z]*D[Ω[z], z]) + (σ0 + σa*z/(1 + z))*(2*h[z]*Ω[z] - Ω[z]^2) + λ
solutiontrial = 


ParametricNDSolve[
  {
   deq2 == 0,
   -1/3*(4*h[z]*Ω[z] - Ω[z]^2 - 2*(1 + z)*h[z]*D[Ω[z], z]) + (x + y*z/(1 + z))*(2* h[z]*Ω[z] - Ω[z]^2) + b == 0, 
   h[0] == 1, Ω[0] == Ω0
  },
 {h, Ω}, {z, 0, 4}, {x, y, b}
]
solmanipulate = h /. solutiontrial;
Quiet[Manipulate[
  Plot[solmanipulate[z][x][y][b], {z, 0, 3}],
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}
 ]]
```

[image]

but I get the following error

[image] .

How could I solve the system from the code, then visualize the solution, such that I can change the parameters and see how the solution changes?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add the Mathematica code instead of a picture so that people can copy your code without retyping it.

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding it, but I am not sure how to make it work tbh. I am new to this.

Comment: The syntax for the `ParametricFunction` should be `solmanipulate[x, y, b][z]`. (Look at the third example in the documentation for `ParametricNDSolve` in the `Examples > Basic Examples` section.)

Comment: Hmm sigma[z] is actually sigma0+sigma a*z/(1+z)

Comment: Okay, update: The suggestion given by march seems to work. Is there a way to write an 'optimization' code, so that the obtained solution (h(z)), which depends on these three parameters, to fit a function, I give?

Comment: If I `Plot[Log[solmanipulate[x, y, b][z]]...]` that gives me a pretty good idea what the function would be that I would want to fit to this. Depends on how precise the fit needs to be. But it is more of a line when the value of `y` is small.

Comment: That's right, but the three parameters seem to be difficult to find, for which the solution fits the following function on the interval (0,3): Sqrt[0.3166*(1 + z)^3 + 0.6847].

Comment: Include `x=.;y=.;b=.;z=.;` at the top of your code to clear any old assignments to the variables that might mess this up. After your code append `{x,y,b}={x,y,b}/.NMinimize[{Total[Table[ (solmanipulate[x,y,b][z]-Sqrt[0.3166*(1+z)^3+0.6847])^2, {z,0,3,.01}]], -5<x<5,-5<y<5,-5<b<5},{x,y,b}][[2]]
Plot[{solmanipulate[x,y,b][z],Sqrt[0.3166*(1+z)^3+0.6847]},{z,0,3}]` The fit varies depending on whether you use `0<z<3` or `0<z<4`. You have both in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answers my question. One last thing: I can modify your code to vary two parameters, if I want to keep one fixed. How to modify your code to vary only one parameter, if two are fixed?

 You could summarize everything in an answer, and I would click accept on it, so that the question is closed.